Free (as in freedom) university math textbooks?
I've stumbled upon Jim Hefferon's "Linear Algebra"
which is a textbook licensed under the GNU Free Documentation License. So I wondered, what are some other university math textbooks that are not simply open access, but licensed under free licenses (by the Free Software Foundation standards)? I'm interested in this because I've found no resource online that aggregates this information and I'd be interested in using any such textbooks for learning right now, and possibly using them to teach in the future, because of all the benefits of a free license.
Any subject is fine, but I'm particularly interested in general topology, differential geometry and analysis textbooks right now.

Excuse my ignorance, but what are the benefits of free licenses for studying/teaching?

Many university teachers make course notes available for download on their Web pages. While they usually don't state a license explicitly, I think most intend them to be freely readable and reusable.

@anankElpis Some benefits I can think of for the teacher are having some content that is "ready", but that can be freely modified and adapted, and being able redistribute it freely also. For the student, in my case, I'd love to have my textbook's sources so that I could create Anki cards more easily and being able to add notes directly to the document. Last but not least, you get to promote free documentation and software.

See https://textbooks.aimath.org/

See also https://www.ams.org/open-math-notes

Here are some sites that collate free-as-in-freedom math texts:

IFORS Developing Countries OR Resources. This site collects open source material related to Operations Research.
LibreTexts Mathematics, part of the wider LibreTexts project, a "multi-institutional collaborative venture to develop the next generation of open-access texts to improve postsecondary education at all levels of higher learning. The LibreTexts approach is highly collaborative where an Open Access textbook environment is under constant revision by students, faculty, and outside experts to supplant conventional paper-based books."
CLP Calculus Textbooks hosts four CC-licensed calculus (in the US sense) textbooks.

